# Trying to implement AsyncTask to make an http request

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've been trying to implement asynctask to make about 30 http requests to find the distance between two locations using a JSON object and the distance matrix api.  The code I've written works when called from the main UI thread, but when I try to run it from the Async Task and save the distances to an array I just end up with an array full of null values.  Any advice? (Note: This code was initially written by someone else at my work, and I've merely copy pasted it and changed a few lines to work with my app.  So, there may be some unnecessary bits that I'm unaware of.  Feel free to point them out)

```
class DistanceFinder extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]>
{   

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... locations) 
        {

        String baseURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=";
        String[] distances = new String[locations[1].length];


        for(int i = 1;i<locations.length;i++)
        {
            String url = baseURL + locations[0][0].replace(" ","+") + "&destinations=" + locations[1][i].replace(' ', '+') + "&sensor=true&units=imperial";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = "";
            boolean internet;
            try 
            {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                    {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        out.close();
                        responseString = out.toString();   
                        internet=true;

                    } 
                    else
                    { 
                            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                             throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    } 
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    internet=false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    internet=false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            if(internet){
                try 
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    JSONArray rows = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
                    JSONObject inRows=rows.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray elements = inRows.getJSONArray("elements");
                    JSONObject inElements=elements.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONObject distance= inElements.getJSONObject("distance");
                    distances[i] = distance.getString("text");

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
        return distances;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        distancesList = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

}
```

Comment: "Any advice?" Add some logging statements or use the debugger to figure out where all the null come from

Comment: your `onPreExecute()` is pointless. You also should not call `super.onPostExecute()`

Comment: Can you post how you populate the location array which is passed to the AsyncTask?

Comment: `Toast.makeText().show()` probably shouldn't be called inside a loop... unless you want to see 30 `Toast`s pop up on top of each other saying the same thing. Also, realize that `IOException` doesn't actually indicate "no data connection". For example, an HTTP 404 response from your web server would cause `FileNotFoundException`, which is a type of `IOException`.

Comment: Add the code you use to call the async task and show specifically when your experiencing the null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with you for loop

```
for(int i = 1;i<locations.length;i++)
```

First, you should start from 0, unless your first cell doesn't store a `String` you wish you check the distance to.

Second, your for loop should be

```
for(int i = 0;i<locations[0].length;i++)
```

Right now you're checking cells `[1][0]` and that's it, because the loop ends.

I tested it with manually entered locations and it works.

Also, just to make things easier for you to debug, You should really get used to using `Log.d()`. It really helps figuring out errors. I used it in your code and saw that the loop only gets executed once.

Good luck

P.s, as mentioned in one of the comments, remove the `onPreExecute()`. You don't use it.

Comment: God, it's always something small like that.  Thank you so much.  Also, I do have something else stored at zero, so there's a reason for that